# Wikipedia plot of $\deg(\mathrm{minpoly})$ of complex numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, complex-numbers

Regarding [the following picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Algebraicszoom.png) on the Wikipedia article for [Algebraic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number):

[image: countable field of the algebraic numbers]

The description is:

> Visualisation of the (countable) field of algebraic numbers in the complex plane. Colours indicate degree of the polynomial the number is a root of (red = linear, i.e. the rationals, green = quadratic, blue = cubic, yellow = quartic...). Points becomes smaller as the integer polynomial coefficients become larger. View shows integers 0,1 and 2 at bottom right, +i near top.

If I understand it correctly, for each pixel $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, let $c = x+i y \in \mathbb{C}.$ The color is a mapping of $\deg(\mathrm{minpoly}(c))$.

If this is the case, then isn't the $\deg(\mathrm{minpoly}(c)) \le 2$ for all $c \in \mathbb{C}?$ Why does the picture has more colors? I think I misunderstood the picture description. What does this plot show?

---

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Stephen_J._Brooks) is the WP talk page for the picture, and if relevant, here is the [source code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Stephen_J._Brooks/algebraics/src).

Comment: "Minimal polynomial" here means the minimal polynomial over the rationals, not the real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the field of algebraic numbers (denoted $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$) is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and so every algebraic element satisfies some polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. So the described minimal polynomials are in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. For example, consider an $n^\text{th}$ root of $2$ in $\mathbb{R}$. It sits inside $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and it's minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^n-2$, so we clearly have minimal polynomials of all positive degrees.

On the other hand, every element of $\mathbb{C}$ (and thus all elements of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ under the canonical inclusion map) satisfy a polynomial of degree at most $2$ over $\mathbb{R}[x]$, which is likely where your confusion is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the definition of "algebraic number" is a complex number that satisfies a monic polynomial with rational coefficients.

For an *algebraic* number $\alpha$, the "minimal polynomial" refers to the monic irreducible polynomial with *rational* coefficients that is satisfied by $\alpha$.

Equivalently, it is the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$).

It is not hard to show that for every $n\gt 0$ there is an algebraic number that has a monic irreducible polynomial of degree  $n$.